# How many functions satisfy this condition?

Tags: functions

> The number of functions $ f:\{1,2,3,4\} \rightarrow \{a \in E: Z \mid
>  a \mid ≤8\} $
>
> satisfying $f(n) + \frac{f(n+1)}{n} = 1,\forall \ n \in \{1,2,3\}$ is

I'm not able to approach this problem at all. I know one probably won't need to find those exact functions but just some manipulation might get the result. Just help me with how to approach the first step and I'll try again.

Comment: What is E? ? ? ?

Comment: @311411 E is the set of numbers that satisfy that specific condition

Comment: What specific condition is that?  Regardless of that, the collections are so small that trial and error should suffice.  Have you found any functions that work?  The fact that $n\,|\,f(n+1)$ is already very restrictive,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(1)+f(2)=1$$
$$f(2)+f(3)/2=1$$

$$f(3)+f(4)/3=1$$

$f(4)$ has to be a multiple of $3$.

If $f(4)=0$, then $f(3)=1$ but $f(3)$ must be even. Hence $f(4)\ne 0$.

If $f(4)=3$, then $f(3)=0, f(2)=1, f(1)=0.$

Now, what other values can $f(4)$ take? Explore them to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Since the functions are on the integer space, we can instead view them as sequences. We can then rephrase the question as, with some rearrangement,

> Find the number of sequences $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $|x_n| \leq 8$, and $x_{n+1} = n (1 - x_n)$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

Comment if you need more help.

Comment: Since the original question just asks for the number, we don't need to worry about generating the actual function.